# change page on success with jQuery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is a stupid simple question, but ive been staring at it all night and can't get it right. I need to change the page on sucess, right now I can only get it to work using .load to load a div from the desired page. I want it to redirect to the entire page.

Here is what I have

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data=="Error") {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#processing").hide();
    } else {
        $("#contain").load("finalPage.php #desiredDiv");
    }
}
```

I just want it to go to that page instead of loading a chunk of it. window.load isn't working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) you'll cause the browser to redirect, like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == "Error") {
        $("#error").show();
        $("#processing").hide();
    } else {
        window.location.href = "finalPage.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thx. Like i said, stupid question. Have been working in PHP all day and was forgetting the ".href" part at the end. much appreciated.